# Sandbox Vs Sandbox Template

Tags: sandbox, connected-apps, app, package-install, partial-sandbox

I am integrating a native app - inspire Planner- into my org. I have a Partial Sandbox that I want to install it into.
I am looking at the documentation and trying to understand the difference between Sandbox Vs Sandbox Template.
Can you please explain to me the benefits and differences of each and what do you suggest I install it into?
I then want to create a partial sandbox. Which tab should I use?
If I install this app in a Partial Sandbox will I be able to deploy it to my salesforce or will I need to install the app again?
Once I have learned this other app can I refresh the partial sandbox in order to then use it for production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sandbox templates allow you to pick specific objects and data to copy to your Full or Partial Copy sandbox to control the size and content of each sandbox. Sandbox templates are only available for use with Full or Partial Copy sandboxes.

When you create a sandbox template, you select the object data (standard and custom) to copy during the creation or refresh of a sandbox.

The sandbox template editor understands the relationships that are defined in your Salesforce org’s object schema. Some objects are included even before you’ve selected anything because they’re required in any org. As you select objects to copy, the editor ensures that the associated required objects are added. To see which related objects are required by an object, select it in the Object table. Required objects are displayed in the Required Objects column.

As you change the schema of the objects in your org, Salesforce updates the template by adding or subtracting related required objects. For example, if Object A is a master of Object B, and you add Object B to a template, Salesforce requires Object A in the template and adds Object A.

For steps, refer this documents:- [Salesforce Template](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_templates.htm&type=5)

for more reference :- [Create SF Template](https://www.tutorialkart.com/salesforce/how-to-create-salesforce-sandbox-template/)